# Bash expr error

Tags: linux, bash

I have a few text files with numbers (structure as below). I'd like to sum up every line form one file with ever line form other files (line1 from file1 + line1 from file2 etc.). I have written the bash script as following but this gives me the `expr error`.

```
function countHourly () {


for i in {1..24}
    do
        for file in $PLACE/*.dailycount.txt
            do
            SECBUFF=`head -n $i $file`
             VAL=`expr $VAL + $SECBUFF` ## <-- this cause expr error

        done
      echo line $i form all files counts: $VAL
done

}
```

file structure *.dailycount.txt:
`1
0
14
56
45
0
3
45
23
23
9` (every number in new line).

Comment: You haven't assigned VAL yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `head -n NUMBER FILE` command outputs the first NUMBER lines. This means that `SECBUFF` ends up being `1 0` on the second run of the loop, and something like `expr 1 + 2 3` is not a valid expression so you get an error from `expr`.

You can use `sed` to pick only the nth line from a file, but I wonder if you shouldn't restructure the program somehow.

```
        SECBUFF=`sed -ne ${i}p $file`
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your files each contain exactly 24 lines, you could solve this problem with a simple one-liner:

```
counthourly() {
  paste -d+ $PLACE/*.dailycount.txt | bc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help. With that variation you could check very input so that only numbers would be added for the sum, even if there are lines that invalid.

```
function countHourly {
    local NUMBERS TOTAL=0 I

    readarray -t NUMBERS < <(cat "$PLACE"/*.dailycount.txt)

    for I in "${NUMBERS[@]}"; do
        [[ $I =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && (( TOTAL += I ))
    done

    echo "Total: $TOTAL"
}
```

Or

```
function countHourly {
    local NUMBERS TOTAL=0 I

    while read I; do
        [[ $I =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && (( TOTAL += I ))
    done < <(cat "$PLACE"/*.dailycount.txt)

    echo "Total: $TOTAL"
}
```